# ASP.NET State Management in appropriate situations

Tags: asp.net, state

There are 6 techniques to manage states in ASP.NET 3.5 (as far as I know).

```
(1) View State
(2) Cross Page Posting
(3) Query String
(4) Session State
(5) Application State
(6) Cookies
```

Can anyone give me some appropriate examples of situations where I should use these techniques?

For example:

```
(*) Session State: Personalization, Buy Cart, etc.
(*) Cookies: Saving User Credentials, etc.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

State management option

View state:

Use when you need to store small amounts of information for a page that will post back to itself. Using the ViewState property provides functionality with basic security.

Control state:

Use when you need to store small amounts of state information for a control between round trips to the server.

Hidden fields:

Use when you need to store small amounts of information for a page that will post back to itself or to another page, and when security is not an issue.

You can use a hidden field only on pages that are submitted to the server.

Cookies:

Use when you need to store small amounts of information on the client and security is not an issue.

Query string:

Use when you are transferring small amounts of information from one page to another and security is not an issue.

You can use query strings only if you are requesting the same page, or another page via a link.

Server Side Management Options

Application state

Use when you are storing infrequently changed, global information that is used by many users, and security is not an issue. Do not store large quantities of information in application state.

Session state

Use when you are storing short-lived information that is specific to an individual session and security is an issue. Do not store large quantities of information in session state. Be aware that a session-state object will be created and maintained for the lifetime of every session in your application. In applications hosting many users, this can occupy significant server resources and affect scalability.

Profile properties

Use when you are storing user-specific information that needs to be persisted after the user session is expired and needs to be retrieved again on subsequent visits to your application.

Database support

Use when you are storing large amounts of information, managing transactions, or the information must survive application and session restarts. Data mining is a concern, and security is an issue.

Comment: for more details go to http://coscientech.blogspot.com or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx

Comment: I also came across The Profile Object and userData Behavior. I guess you should check this out on msdn.microsoft.com

Comment: In ASP.NET I also came across the Profile object and UserData behavior. for more search msdn.

Answer (score 15):

There's a lot of factors that can influence this, so I won't comment on all of them.  But here are a few pointers:

- `ViewState` - This is useful when you'll be posting back to the same page frequently (something you're practically forced into doing by ASP.Net Webforms).  How useful it is exactly changes depending on what kind of app you're building.  For public internet sites, it should be used very sparingly.  You may even want to turn it off by default.  For local intranet sites, it's a great tool — especially for the fewer, heavier, webforms pages.
- `Query String` - Use this to store state that you need to allow the user to bookmark a page or process and come back to much later.  Even then, you might want to keep it down to some kind of hash that you can use as a key in a database lookup to avoid a really huge url (though hashes have their own problems).  Also, a lot of users like to fiddle with your query string directly, so it can be dangerous to put too much here.  It's easy to accidentally expose data to users who aren't supposed to see it this way.
- `Application State` - Remember that this is shared by all users, so use appropriately.  Things like view counts can go here.
- `Cookies` - Don't use cookies to store user credentials.  They're just plain unencrypted text files.  Use cookies to store a key into the session (even here you can and should now use cookie-less sessions) and simple personalization settings that will be specific to that user and browser.  For example, my monitor size at work is different from home, and so putting display size/layout settings into a cookie is nice because the settings stick for each computer, but it isn't going to compromise my security any if someone else reads that information.

Now I want to highlight this concept from the "Query String" section:

> you might want to keep it down to some kind of hash that you can use as a key in a database lookup

Again, hashes have their own problems, but I want to point out that several items on my list talk (including Query String) about uploading data from the client web browser to the web server: ViewState, Query String, Cookie, and Cross-Page Post.  You want to minimize the data that you move from client to server.  This concept applies to all of these, and for several reasons:

1. Pulling data from the client is *slow* for public internet sites.  Even broadband connections typically cripple the bandwidth available for upload.  512Kpbs (still a typical broadband upload rate in many areas) is *nothing* when compared to the Gigabit Ethernet (or faster) connection that likely sits between your database and your web server.  As much as you might think of a database query as slow (and it is), it's still likely a much better way to go than waiting for the same data to arrive from the client.
2. Keeping the data on the server is cheaper, because you don't pay for the bandwidth required to push it to or from the client, and bandwidth often costs as much or more than your server hardware.
3. It's more secure, because if done right even when a client's computer or connection is compromised all the hacker has access to initially is a hash key that likely expires by the time he can decrypt it.  Of course, if done wrong he can use that key directly immediately, so you still need to be careful.

So for most things, what I recommend is to start out by keeping a database key in the Session and then have code to easily pull what you need from a database based on that key.  As you experience bottlenecks, *profile* to find out where they are and start caching those pages or controls, or keep that data/query result in the session directly.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you mean the **Cache** object by Application State.

The Cache object is a great way to manage application wide state, e.g. to record source and count access to your website (to prevent DDOS attacks for example).

Comment: The cache object is a great place to store static data (or any data that doesnt change much but is referenced by your app) to prevent having to read from the database or file system every time.

Answer (score 1):

(3) Query String
(4) Session State
(5) Application State
(6) Cookies

**1. Viewstate**

- *Disclaimer*: Use as little as possible. Good point is to *always* have each state reachable by an url, if possible.

  - F.e. Paging should use the URL (so `/url/?p=2` instead of storing the page in Viewstate)
- Use to persist control state between page-cycles.

  - F.e. Store the selected item in a checkbox, so you can determine whether it has changed.

**2. Cross Page Posting**

Don't. See the disclaimer for viewstate. Use the URL for this, or store the data in a session / cookie / profile if loads of properties need to be kept around.

Major downside of CPP is that the user cannot use the 'Back' and 'Forward' buttons in it's webbrowser. When a user clicks the back button it wants to undo everything on that page and retry the last one. When using CPP to click them through a wizard; this behavior is not possible without a lot of 'Are you sure you want to resend blablablabl'.

**3. Query String**

Use alot. Every visible state that a page could reach should be accessible by URL. People with screenreaders will thank you for this. And by using the query string there is no need to use javascript-only solutions.

```
/url/?page=2    // when doing paging, don't use postback for this
/url/?tab=advanced-search    // when having tabs on top of your page
```

etc.

**4. Session state**

Use this for short-living objects, that only make sense *this* time the visitor visits your site. For example:

- Which step of a certain wizard was reached
- Pages a user had visited before
- Small objects you want to put in cache, but that are user-bound

Don't use sessions but profiles for things like:

- Preferences
- Selected language

Because those things also make sense the next time the user visits your site.

**5. Application state**

Never. Use ASP.NET cache, or memcached, or any caching framework for this.

**6. Cookies**

Session ID, Profile ID for authenticated users; user preferences for anonymous users (everything listed in the second list under 4.).